# 401 Unauthorized on unprotected resource

Tags: reactjs, rest, jwt, react-admin, api-platform.com

### My Setup

I have a server with a REST API that runs on Symfony with API Platform. The GET requests for my resources do not require authorization, however the other operations do. Authorization is handled with a JWT Bearer token.

The client uses React-admin with API Platform Admin. I added this code to send the JWT token along with the operations:

```js
// dataProvider.js
import React from "react";
import { hydraDataProvider, fetchHydra as baseFetchHydra } from "@api-platform/admin";

export default entrypoint => {

    const fetchHeaders = { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}` };
    const fetchHydra = (url, options = {}) => baseFetchHydra(url, {
        ...options,
        headers: new Headers(fetchHeaders),
    });

    return hydraDataProvider(entrypoint, fetchHydra);
};
```

---

### The Problem

When I log in to my admin interface now, I get a `401 Unauthorized` response, because the server did not expect a token for a GET request.

**Request Headers**:

```
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0
Accept: application/ld+json
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1ODQ2NzcwMTYsImV4cCI6MTU4NDY4MDYxNiwicm9sZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiJdLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IlNvbWVib2R5In0.O_StagfEJy5VQS-5s-DjuwzOlUgrl3MTmxPfZUU0J1go06tKOpLjiBrEIJpjo5AK67w93SfsUaIBop8apoacHQ
Content-Type: application/ld+json
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
TE: Trailers
```

**Response Headers**:

```
HTTP/2 401 Unauthorized
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000
access-control-expose-headers: link
cache-control: no-cache, private
content-type: application/json
date: Fri, 20 Mar 2020 04:40:39 GMT
link: <https://localhost:8000/api/docs.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation"
www-authenticate: Bearer
x-debug-token: 720652
x-debug-token-link: https://localhost:8000/_profiler/720652
x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.1
x-robots-tag: noindex
content-length: 282
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

When I manually remove the Authorization line from the request headers in the browser and retry it, it works.

---

### My Questions:

1. Is this even expected behavior?
2. Should the client *always* send the token?

   - If the token should always be sent, how do I tell API Platform to accept it even if it isn't needed?
   - If the token should only be sent when it's required, how do I let the hydraDataProvider know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many many hours of trying different solutions, I finally fixed this problem.

### Answers to my Questions

1. No, sending a valid token should not result in a 401 response.
2. The token can be sent on every request.

### My Solution

The problem was that the JWT authentication was configured incorrectly on my server. None of the guides I followed actually covered the following case:
**I have the user email as identifier, not the user name.**

So what ended up happening is that the token contained the encoded **user name**, which is not a unique identifier in my case. To tell JWT to use the email instead, I had to set the **user_identity_field** to **email**.

```yaml
// config/packages/lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    user_identity_field: email
```